# $g(n)=\omega (1)$ then for every $k∈\mathbb{N} $ implies $g(n^{k+1}))-g(n^k)= \Theta(g(n^{k+1}))$?

Tags: algorithms, contest-math

$g(n)=\omega (1)$  then for  every $k∈\mathbb{N} $  implies  $g(n^{k+1}))-g(n^k)= \Theta(g(n^{k+1}))$

when $g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}+$

ps: $g(n)=\omega (1)$  means that for evert $k>0$ there is a $m>0$ that for every $n>=m$ we get $g(n)>=k*1$ 
or in other words $ \lim_{n\to
\infty} 1/g(n)=0$

and $\Theta$ is big theta notatin

Comment: What is $\omega(1)$? Does your initial statement mean $g(n)$ is constant?

Comment: ω(1) means that for evert k>0 there is a m>0 that for every n>=m we get g(n)>=1

Comment: What are $\omega$ and $\Theta$?

Comment: i updated the question for you

Comment: @big-lion see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that, but I was only familiar with $o$ and O$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.**

Take $g\colon \mathbb{N}\to [0,\infty)$ defined by $g(n) = \log\log n$ for $n\geq 10$ large enough (and $g(n)=1$ for $n< 10$). *(This is a technically to make sure $g>0$ even for small $n$.)* Then $g(n) = \omega(1)$ as required, yet, for any fixed $k\geq 1$ and $n\geq 10$,
$$
g(n^{k+1}) - g(n^{k}) = \log (k+1) + \log\log n - \log k - \log\log n = \log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right) = \Theta(1)
$$
while
$$
g(n^{k+1}) = \log (k+1) + \log\log n = \omega(1)\,.
$$

Comment: wow thank you so much i don't know how you thought about it this fast ?is it by practicing a lot ?

Comment: @newprogrammerha Yes, more or less. $\log$'s and $\exp$ are a good source of counterexamples...

Comment: yeah i noticed ! i am gonna keep practicing as much as i can ! thank you again

Comment: @newprogrammerha You're welcome! (If you are satisfied with this answer, whenever you get a chance you can accept it by clicking on the $\checkmark$ symbol on the left.)

Comment: i forgot good thing you reminded me lol

Comment: i have a question : why log(1+(1/k) = theta(1) ? i think this is not true .. i think  log(1+(1/k) =o(1) only , but this will also prove the example you gave i think ..

Comment: @newprogrammerha Here, $k$ is an (arbitrary) constant, and the variable that goes to infinity is $n$. So for any fixed $k$, $\log(1+1/k)$ is a (strictly positive) constant.

Comment: ok but $log(1+1/k)$   will never be bigger than 1 ! since$ k>=1$

Comment: because we are trieng to prove that $log(1+1/k) >= c * 1$ when $c>=1$ also

Comment: @newprogrammerha Indeed, but what does that change? (it's still $\Theta(1)$ as it is a positive constant; but more importantly, even if you replace $\Theta(1)$ by $O(1)$, the counterexample holds. You have the first being $O(1)$, and the second $\omega(1)$ (i.e., going to $\infty$, so they cannot be $\Theta$ of each other)

Comment: @newprogrammerha No. Again, this doesn't change anything, but in the definition of $\Theta(1)$ (or $\Theta(n)$, or anything big-O related) the constants do not have to be $\geq 1$, only $>0$.

Comment: yeah i understand that they are not Θ of eachother and i know it won't change a thin , but i want to understand why you wrote that $log(1+1/k)= /Theta(1) $ because i think that $log(1+1/k)= O(1) $  because i just can't prove that $log(1+1/k)= /Omega(1) $ also cause  it just doesn't make sense

Comment: oh my god i am so sorry i just thought c>=1 instead of >0 i am stupid sorry

Comment: @newprogrammerha Take $n_0=1$ and $c = \log(1+1/k)>0$. For every $n\geq n_0$, we have $c\cdot 1 \leq \log(1+1/k)$, which shows by definition that $\log(1+1/k) = \Omega(1)$ when $n\to \infty$.

Comment: @newprogrammerha No worries. We all have these moments.